# Populate values in a textbox from the database using servlets and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have the following data in the database. I want to populate my text fields by populating this data using servlets and ajax.

data_id        ------------------------      char(30)
Lat           --------------------------double precision
Long           ------------------------- double precision

**Info.class**

```
package org.bean

 public class Info {

private String data_id;
    private String lat;
    private String long;



     public void setData_id(String data_id) {
    this.data_id = data_id;
}
public String getData_id() {
    return data_id;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLong(String long) {
    this.long = long;
}

public String getLong() {
    return long;
}

}
```

**FetchData.class**

```
public class FetchData {

private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    if (connection != null)
        return connection;
    else {
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream inputStream =                  

            FetchData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
            prop.load(inputStream);
            String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
            String url = prop.getProperty("url");
            String user = prop.getProperty("user");
            String password = prop.getProperty("password");
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

}

public static ArrayList<Info> getAllInfo() {
    connection = FetchData.getConnection();
    ArrayList<Info> inf = new ArrayList<Info>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from info_table");

        while(rs.next()) {  
            Info in=new Info();
            in.setData_id(rs.getString("data_id"));
            in.setLat(rs.getString("Lat"));
            in.setLong(rs.getString("Long"));
            inf.add(in);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inf;
}
}
```

**PopulateTable.class**

```
public class PopulateTable extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PopulateTable() {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ArrayList<Info> in=new ArrayList<Info>();
    in=FetchData.getAllInfo();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(in, new TypeToken<List<Info>>() {}.getType());

    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#tablediv").hide();
 $("#showTable").click(function(event){
       $.get('PopulateTable',function(responseJson) {
           if(responseJson!=null){
               $("#infotable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
               var table1 = $("#infotable");
               $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                       rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['data_id']); 
                       rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['lat']); 
                       rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['long']);
                       rowNew.appendTo(table1);
               });
            }
        });
        $("#tablediv").show();          
 });      
});
</script>
</head>

 <input type="button" value="Show Table" id="showTable"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="infotable"> 
<tr> 
    <th scope="col">Data_id</th> 
    <th scope="col">Latitude</th> 
    <th scope="col">Longitude</th> 

</tr> 
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am basically populating the database data in a table using servlets and ajax on a jsp page without refreshing the page. I want the same action to be taken. Instead of onclick of a button I want the user to enter data_id and onkeyup event of that textfield Latitude and longitude values to be populated from the database. how do i do this.

If i change the jsp page to

```
<input type="text" id="data_id" onblur=""/>
<input type="text" id="latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="longitude"/>
```

then onblur event should populate my textfields having id latitude  and longitude with the data corresponding to the typed id. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your Ajax call inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});` put it in a function with a name and have your onblur call it:

```
function populatefields()
{
  ... //Ajax stuff
}
...
...
<input type="text" id="data_id" onblur="populatefields()" />
```

Comment: thank u sir. but what do i do to retrieve the corresponding values? for example I enter a data_id in my textbox and then onblur event I need to display corresonding latitude and longitude fields?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the values from the json, or how to put them in the text fields? Assuming the way you are getting them from the json is right, you can put them in the fields by `document.getElementById('lattitude').value = value['lat'];` or the jquery way `$("#lattitude").value = value['lat'];`

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Logger"%>
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Level"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JFrame"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JButton"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Student view</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script>
    function selectItem()
    {
    var sel=document.getSelection("drop").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("drop").value;
    var xmlhttp,url;
    if(c=="hand")
        url="StudentView_2.jsp";
    else
        url="StudentView.jsp";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
}
else
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //for IE6, IE5
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { 
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {

            document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } 
        else
        {
            alert('Something is wrong !!');
        }
    }

    }
}

    </script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="topPan"> <!--<a href="http://www.free-css.com/"><img src="" alt="Education Zone" width="245" height="37" border="0"  class="logo" title="Education Zone"/></a>-->
    <h1> <p>Library Manager</p></h1>
  <div id="topContactPan"> </div>
  <div id="topMenuPan">
    <div id="topMenuLeftPan"></div>
    <div id="topMenuMiddlePan">
      <ul>
          <li class="home"><a href="StudentView.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.jsp">Logout</a></li>


<!--        <li class="contact"><a href="" class="contact">Contact</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="topMenuRightPan"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bodyPan">
  <div id="bodyLeftPan">
    <h2><span>Student View</span> </h2>
<!--    <p>Education Zone is a free, tableless, W3C-compliant web design layout by <span>Template World</span>. This template has been tested and proven compatible with all major browser environments and operating systems. You are free to modify the design to suit your tastes in any way you like.</p>
    <p>We only ask you to not remove "Design by Template World" and the link <span>http://www.templateworld.com</span> from the footer of the template.</p>
    <p>If you are interested in seeing more of our free web template designs feel free to visit our website, Template World. We intend to add at least 25 new <span>free templates</span> in the coming month.</p>
    -->


<!--    <form action="StudentView_1.jsp">
        <input type="submit" value="View All Books"  >
    </form>   
    <form action="StudentView_2.jsp">
        <input type="submit" value="In Hand"  >
    </form> -->
<form >
    <select name="drop" id="drop" onchange="selectItem()">

        <option value="view" >View All</option>
        <option value="hand">In Hand</option>
    </select>
        <!--<input type="" value="In Hand"  >-->
    </form>
   <%
//       try{
//            // TODO add your handling code here:
//            String [] colname={"Book Id","Book Name","Book Author"};
//            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","mysql");
//            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
//            System.out.println("success");
//            String sql1="select * from book where Available='1'";
//            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql1);
//            int n=0,i=0;
//            while(rs.next())
//            {   
//               n++;
//            }
//            rs.beforeFirst();
//            Object [][] o=new Object[n][3];
//            out.println("<table border=1>");
//            out.println("<tr><td>Book Id</td><td>Book Name</td><td>Book Author</td></tr>");
//            
//            while(rs.next())
//            {
//             o[i][0]=rs.getString(1);
//             o[i][1]=rs.getString(2);
//             o[i][2]=rs.getString(3);
//             out.println("<tr><td>"+o[i][0]+"</td><td>"+o[i][1]+"</td><td>"+o[i][2]+"</td></tr>");
//             i++;
//            }
//            out.println("</table>");
//            
//       }catch(Exception ee)
//       {
//           
//       }
    //   Object ss=request.getParameter("xx");
       //System.out.println(ss);
      // session.setAttribute("pp",ss );
   %>

  </div>
  <form>

  </form>
   <div id="message1" class="aaa">



<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"  %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<%!

public int Converter(String str)

{   

    int convrtr=0;

    if(str==null)

        {

            str="0";

        }

    else if((str.trim()).equals("null"))

        {

            str="0";

        }

    else if(str.equals(""))

        {

            str="0";

        }

    try{

            convrtr=Integer.parseInt(str);

        }

    catch(Exception e)

        {

        }

    return convrtr;

}

%>

<%

    Connection con = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root", "mysql");



    ResultSet rsPgin = null;

    ResultSet rsRwCn = null;

    PreparedStatement psPgintn=null;

    PreparedStatement psRwCn=null;



    // Number of records displayed on each page

    int iSwRws=4;  

    // Number of pages index displayed

    int iTotSrhRcrds=10; 



    int iTotRslts=Converter(request.getParameter("iTotRslts"));

    int iTotPags=Converter(request.getParameter("iTotPags"));

    int iPagNo=Converter(request.getParameter("iPagNo"));

    int cPagNo=Converter(request.getParameter("cPagNo"));



    int iStRsNo=0;

    int iEnRsNo=0;



    if(iPagNo==0)

        {

            iPagNo=0;

        }

    else{

            iPagNo=Math.abs((iPagNo-1)*iSwRws);

        }



    String sqlPgintn="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM book limit "+iPagNo+","+iSwRws+"";

    psPgintn=con.prepareStatement(sqlPgintn);

    rsPgin=psPgintn.executeQuery();

    // Count total number of fetched rows

    String sqlRwCnt="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as cnt";

    psRwCn=con.prepareStatement(sqlRwCnt);

    rsRwCn=psRwCn.executeQuery();



    if(rsRwCn.next())

      {

        iTotRslts=rsRwCn.getInt("cnt");

      }

%>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Pagination using JSP page</title>

    </head>

<body>

    <form name="frm">

        <input type="hidden" name="iPagNo" value="<%=iPagNo%>">

        <input type="hidden" name="cPagNo" value="<%=cPagNo%>">

        <input type="hidden" name="iSwRws" value="<%=iSwRws%>">



        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" >

        <tr>

        <td>BookId</td>

        <td>BookName</td>

        <td>BookAuthor</td>

        </tr>

<%

    while(rsPgin.next())

      {

%>

        <tr>

            <td><%=rsPgin.getString(1)%></td>

            <td><%=rsPgin.getString(2)%></td>

            <td><%=rsPgin.getString(3)%></td>

            <td><a href="www.google.com>view </a></td>

        </tr>

<% 

     }

%>

<%

    // Calculate next record start and end position 

    try{

        if(iTotRslts<(iPagNo+iSwRws))

            {

                iEnRsNo=iTotRslts;

            }

        else

            {

                iEnRsNo=(iPagNo+iSwRws);

            }



            iStRsNo=(iPagNo+1);

            iTotPags=((int)(Math.ceil((double)iTotRslts/iSwRws)));

        }

    catch(Exception e)

        {

                e.printStackTrace();

        }

%>

<tr>

<td colspan="3">

<div>

<%

     // Create index of pages 

    int i=0;

    int cPge=0;

    if(iTotRslts!=0)

       {

        cPge=((int)(Math.ceil((double)iEnRsNo/(iTotSrhRcrds*iSwRws))));

        int prePageNo=(cPge*iTotSrhRcrds)-((iTotSrhRcrds-1)+iTotSrhRcrds);

        if((cPge*iTotSrhRcrds)-(iTotSrhRcrds)>0)

            {

        %>

        <a href="StudentView.jsp?iPagNo=<%=prePageNo%>&cPagNo=<%=prePageNo%>"><< Previous</a>

        <%

        }



        for(i=((cPge*iTotSrhRcrds)-(iTotSrhRcrds-1));i<=(cPge*iTotSrhRcrds);i++)

        {

            if(i==((iPagNo/iSwRws)+1))

            {

            %>

        <a href="StudentView.jsp?iPagNo=<%=i%>" style="cursor:pointer;color:red"><b><%=i%></b></a>

            <%

            }

            else if(i<=iTotPags)

            {

            %>

        <a href="StudentView.jsp?iPagNo=<%=i%>"><%=i%></a>

            <% 

            }

        }



        if(iTotPags>iTotSrhRcrds&& i<iTotPags)

        {

         %>

        <a href="StudentView.jsp?iPagNo=<%=i%>&cPagNo=<%=i%>">>> Next</a>

        <%

        }

      }

      %>

    <b>Rows <%=iStRsNo%> - <%=iEnRsNo%>   Total Result  <%=iTotRslts%></b>

</div>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<%

try{

    if(psPgintn!=null){

        psPgintn.close();

    }

    if(rsPgin!=null){

        rsPgin.close();

    }   

    if(psRwCn!=null){

        psRwCn.close();

    }

    if(rsRwCn!=null){

        rsRwCn.close();

    }

    if(con!=null){

        con.close();

    }

  }

catch(Exception e)

  {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

%>


   </div>
<!--<table id="message1" align="left" width="200" border="1" class="aaa">
</table>-->
<!--<form>
<select name="message1" id="message1">

</select>
</form>-->
  <div id="bodyRightPan1">


  </div>
</div>
<div id="footermainPan">
  <div id="footerPan">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a>| </li>
      <li><a href="Registration.jsp">Registration</a>| </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="copyright">©education zone. All right reserved.</p>
    <ul class="templateworld">
      <li>design by:</li>
      <li><a href="http://www.templateworld.com" target="_blank">Template World</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="footerPanhtml"><a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" target="_blank">HTML</a></div>
    <div id="footerPancss"><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank">css</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not post your code directly. You shall give your explanation to the code that you have posted as an answer here.